# React Native firebase email verification user.user.sendEmailVerification is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to create an app using firebase. here my code:

```
const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
await user.user.sendEmailVerification()
```

user is initializing in firebase authentication but this is happening :

```
TypeError: user.user.sendEmailVerification is not a function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**since firebase 9 :**

```
auth =getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password)
        .then(userCredential=>userCredential.user)
        .then(user=>{sendEmailVerification(user)})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74663537/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async-await` syntax with `try-catch` this way :

```js
try {
  const { user } = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  await user.sendEmailVerification();
  return user;
} catch(e) {
  return e;
}
```

Comment: This works very well for me in my local environment

Comment: Of course I understand, but your code is supposed to work. Maybe `user` is `undefined` and creating it in a `try-catch` can allow you to raise an error. You can also try the `auth().` format instead of passing it as a parameter.

Comment: still same error